# Conditional equivalent class in DAGs (Bayesian network, causal graph)

Tags: conditional-probability, causality, dag

Suppose we are dealing with a prediction problem, the target variable is $Y$, the predictive covariates are chosen from $\mathbf{X}=\{X_1,X_2,...,X_n\}$. The causal graph (DAG) on $Y,\mathbf{X}$ is known.

We hope to predict $Y$ with a selected subset of $\mathbf{X}$, for example, predicting $Y$ with the conditional probability $Pr(Y|X_1,X_2)$

My questions are:

- For any selected subsets $\mathbf{X}_c=\{X_{c_1},...,X_{c_k}\} \sqsubset \mathbf{X}$, how to construct its equivalent class $E_c$, such that any $\mathbf{X}_c^\prime \in E_c$ satisifies $Pr(Y|\mathbf{X}_c)=Pr(Y|\mathbf{X}_c^\prime)$ ?
- Is it possible to bound the number of all equivalent classes (w.r.t to $n$), imposing some structural assumptions on the DAG, such as bounded treewidth, max/avg (in-) degree ?

Any possible ideas to solve the problem, or related-papers are welcomed.

Comment: Are you really trying to get to `P(Y|X_1,X_2)` or are you perhaps interested in the prediction of `E(Y|X_1,X_2)` which would be the common quantity of interest in e.g. regression.

Comment: Indeed, $E(Y|X_1,X_2)$ is my ultimate objective. I describe the problem with $P(Y|X_1,X_2)$ for clearity.

Comment: @Scriddie, Hi, any solution or possible ideas to the question, especially the second one, is welcomed.